# SharePoint 2010 and OWA web parts authentication

Tags: authentication, windows-authentication

I have SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and Exchange server 2010 SP1 installed.
I added "My Inbox" web part for each user in his "my site". The problem is when the user is opening the page; the login window prompts two times, first one for SharePoint authentication, and the second one for Exchange Authentication.
Is there any way to authenticate the OWA when the user is authenticated to the SharePoint. 
The OWA exchange server is configured to "Integrated Windows authentication".
SharePoint is configured to "Windows authentication"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I seem to recall the only way to do that was with Kerberos, I'm not positive, so that's why I'm commenting and not making it an answer.

Comment: We have have the SharePoint web application setup with Kerberos. and On "My Site" we have added owainbox.dwp. But still everytime you go to My site it prompts to log on to the web mail.

Answer (score 4):

To use the Outlook Web Access web parts such as MyInbox, MyTasks and MyCalendar requires authentication to the data inside of Exchange.  If you want it to work automatically, then you need to have the SharePoint web application setup with Kerberos.

This allows the user's credential passed to SharePoint to be forwarded (delegated) to another system.  This is referred to as a double hop.  It is also needed to support most of the BI features where the user's credentials/identity is passed back to SQL server for reporting or other similar integration scenarios.

Here is an article on how to plan and setup Kerberos:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806870.aspx

Here is another article on setting it up:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/20/configuring-kerberos-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Please see this link. It may help you to solve the problem
http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2011/01/17/configuring-multiple-owa-ecp-virtual-directories-on-exchange-2010-client-access-server.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But do you mean to create another virtual directory for the exchange? if yes; then what?